# How to troubleshoot BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.8.2) failed running > Missing System.Diagnostics.Tracing

Tags: unity-game-engine

> Unity 2021.3.16f1
>
> Windows 10
>
> Build Target: Android - Quest 2
>
> Scripting Engine: IL2CPP
>
> Render Enginge: URP 12.1.8 (requires Burst 1.8.2)

For some reason, the build fails when trying to reference **System.Diagnostics.Tracing**

I looked on NuGet, and there doesn't seem to be a 4.2.0.0 release of this package to begin with

I'm going to try to debug this, but i'm pretty stumped.

I've cleared my project-level package caches, my system-level package caches.
Restarted unity, my pc

I even tried making a fresh unity project and it runs into the same issues

about the only thing i haven't done is a clean reinstall of unity.

If anyone is interested, I'll post the minimum reproducible test case to github

Full Log Output:

```
    BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.8.2) failed running
    
    stdout:
    Error: Failed to find entry-points:
    System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Buffers.DefaultArrayPool`1.Rent(Int32 minimumLength)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.Storage.StringCollection.AddString(String value)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.ProcessAssemblyReference(AssemblyReferenceHandle assemblyReferenceHandle, StringCollection strings)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.ProcessAssemblyReferences(StringCollection strings)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<HashImpl>b__3()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.HashImpl()
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.HashAssembly(String filePath, TaskFactory taskFactory)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheRuntime.HashCacheLoader.CreateHashingResult(AssemblyNameReference assemblyNameReference, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, DebugLogWriter debugLogWriter)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheRuntime.HashCacheAssemblyStore.GetAssemblyState(String assemblyName, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.LoadAllAssemblyReferences(AssemblyDefinition asmDef, Dictionary`2 visited, Dictionary`2 jobProducers, HashCacheAssemblyStore assemblyStore, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.EntryPointMethodFinder.FindEntryPoints(String[] rootAssemblyNames, HashCacheAssemblyStore assemblyStore, AssemblyLoader assemblyLoader, NativeCompilerOptions options, ProfileDelegate profileCallback, Boolean includeRootAssemblyReferences, Boolean splitTargets, DebugLogWriter debugWriter)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Server.FindMethodsJob.Execute(CompilerServerJobExecutionContext context)
    ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    File name: 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    File name: 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    
    === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
     (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///K:/Code/RingPlanetOrbit/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/.Runtime/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
    Calling assembly : System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: K:\Code\RingPlanetOrbit\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.burst@1.8.2\.Runtime\bcl.exe.Config
    LOG: Using host configuration file: 
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.0 redirected to 4.2.0.0.
    LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/Code/RingPlanetOrbit/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/.Runtime/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/Code/RingPlanetOrbit/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/.Runtime/System.Diagnostics.Tracing/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/Code/RingPlanetOrbit/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/.Runtime/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EXE.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///K:/Code/RingPlanetOrbit/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/.Runtime/System.Diagnostics.Tracing/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EXE.
    
       at System.Buffers.DefaultArrayPool`1.Rent(Int32 minimumLength)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.Storage.StringCollection.AddString(String value)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.ProcessAssemblyReference(AssemblyReferenceHandle assemblyReferenceHandle, StringCollection strings)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.ProcessAssemblyReferences(StringCollection strings)
       at Burst.Compiler.IL.Hashing.CacheBuilder.ILHasher.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<HashImpl>b__3()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    
    <---
    
    stderr:
    
    Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1728)
    Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1594)
    Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1569)
    Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BurstAOTSettings settings, UnityEditor.Compilation.Assembly[] playerAssemblies) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:710)
    Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor.DoGenerate (UnityEditor.Compilation.Assembly[] assemblies) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:265)
    Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAOTCompilerPostprocessor.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.8.2/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:189)
    UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <11d97693183d4a6bb35c29ae7882c66b>:0)
    UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution might be to update your visual studio install to install .Net Desktop Development and Desktop Development development with c++.

Check forum issue [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-buildfailedexception-burst-compiler-1-1-2-failed-running.721793/)